# How can I read an NFC tag into a texbox of a webpage on an android device?

Tags: android, html, nfc

I would like to read an RFID MIFARE Classic 1k tag into a textbox on a webpage on an HTC One. It supports the protocol, but any pointers how to read this into a web application would be much appreciated. I have no idea where to start.